# Map object to another object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say we get an object like this

```
let formA = {
"a1": 1, "b1":2, "c1":3, 
"a2": 11, "b2":12, "c2":13, 
"a3": 21, "b3":22, "c3":23
}
```

And what we have is

```
let formB = {
"a1": 0, "b1":0, "c1":0, 
"a2": 0, "b2":0, "c2":0
}
```

And the result must be

```
let result = [
{"a1": 1, "b1":2, "c1":3, "a2": 11, "b2":12, "c2":13}, // Form B
{"a1": 21, "b1":22, "c1":23, "a2": 0, "b2":0, "c2":0}  // Form B
]
```

Once the given object properties gets filled up, it must create a new object for the remaining mapped like series.

Comment: I don't get how these are related.

Comment: @Bergi For better standing I just updated the variable names considering them as form objects,
I want to generate two different forms of "formB". But the problem is it has only 6 fields,
hence for the remaining fields which is a3, b3, c3 must be filled out to a new form of "formB". Then the new formB must have a1 = formA's a3,  b1 = formA's b3, c1 = formA's c3

Comment: So formB is more like a struct or model to be filled in with the values of formA in series?  Does that mean that the keys in formA are actually superfluous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builds an array that holds the number of formB shaped objects needed to contain all values of formA.
Builds [key,value] pairs by filling in the values using values from formA in groups of values of the number of formB's key/values.  Turns it into an Object using fromEntries.

```js
let formA = {
"a1": 1, "b1":2, "c1":3, 
"a2": 11, "b2":12, "c2":13, 
"a3": 21, "b3":22, "c3":23
}

let formB = {
"a1": 0, "b1":0, "c1":0, 
"a2": 0, "b2":0, "c2":0
}

const keys = Object.keys(formB)
const values = Object.values(formA)

console.log(
// build array that is formA.size/formB.size rounded up, map values
Array(Math.ceil(values.length/keys.length)).fill().map((obj,i) => 
  // build object using keys from formB, with values from formA
  Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key,j)=>[key,values[i*keys.length+j]||0])))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post isn't clear, but I think you're trying to just merge two objects into one.

This can be done with the `es6 spread operator`. [Here is the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for the `spread operator`.

Here is an example I wrote to show how you can use the `spread operator` to merge two objects and then log the key/values of the merged object:

```
let object1 = {
    firstKey: 'firstValue',
    secondKey: 'secondValue'
};

let object2 = {
    secondObjectKey: 'secondObjectValue'
}


let mergeObjects = {...object1, ...object2};


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(mergeObjects)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

You can also view the example in [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-elbakyan-pqvyh?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Made an attempt to help out and offer a solution to an unclear question and I get downvoted. 

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I feel that it's justified.  OP has not shown minimal effort, his post is unclear and low grade, and the answer you've posted does not appear to provide a solution that matches OP's problem and input/output, or really anything of particular value other than stating that merging objects is possible with a certain type of syntax.  It fits under the discouraged "not an answer" category and OP's question should be closed not answered.  You would have to at least provide some kind of context and PoC to show that this will lead to a solution to OP's query.

Comment: @NickKinlen I just updated the post and made a comment explaining the flow. Pls check